# Dropdown on hover with pure CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add dropdown on hover, the issue is, half the time it's a race to get to a link before `hover` isn't applied. Any ideas?

```css
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu
{
    display: block;
}
.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle:active
{
    /*Without this, clicking will make it sticky*/
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: this isn't pure css - it is bootstrap

Comment: Please, could you explain, with a bit more detail, what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because there is a small gap between the button and the dropdown menu.

You can either remove this gap by removing the top margin on `.dropdown-menu`:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

or, if you would like to keep the current positioning of the menu, you could use a hidden pseudo element to prevent the cursor from leaving the bounds of the button when moving to the menu.

Here I have coloured the pseudo element in red so that you can see how it fills in the gap. You would set this to transparent.

This is only an issue on larger view ports so the media query will prevent the pseudo element appearing on mobile screens.

Use the "Full page" button:

```css
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu
{
    display: block;
}
.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle:active
{
    /*Without this, clicking will make it sticky*/
    pointer-events: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .dropdown:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;

    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Turnip. Really does annoy me in regards to downvotes on this forum sometimes. Thanks for your answer, it works a charm.

Comment: Hi @GerryHodson, I understood your question immediately because I have come across this problem before. For others, your question may have been a little unclear. I would assume that this was the reason for the downvotes. Try to be very explicit when describing the problem. Rather than _"half the time it's a race to get to a link before hover isn't applied"_ I would have said something like _"As I move my cursor from the button to the dropdown menu, the menu automatically closes as though I am no longer hovering the element."_

Comment: @GerryHodson I too have also run across this issue before, so to help alleviate the unnecessary downvotes   i have given you an up vote. Folks are too quick to downvote on this site sometimes!